# validation plugin is not taking bootstrap 3.0 class has-success on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i am using [Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/). and it's working fine. here i want to addClass `has-success & has-error` on success and error. but it's adding class. it's printing **ok** on successful validation. and it's validating only first field. if i field your name field and i keep email address blank then also it's submiting form...

```
 <form action="" method="" id="contact">
        <div class="form-group"">
            <label> Your Name </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="firstname" required="" minlength="5"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Your E-mail </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="email"/>
        </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"> Send</button>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $('#contact').validate({
   success: function(label){
   label.addClass("has-success").text("ok");
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I am using Validation Plugin and it's working fine. Here I want to
>   addClass `has-success` & `has-error` on success and error."*

By default the plugin adds a class called `.error` when there's an error and changes the class to `.valid` when the error is cleared.

You can simply use the default `.error` and `.valid` classes or you can replace them using the `errorClass` and `validClass` options of the plugin:

```
$('#contact').validate({
    errorClass: 'has-error',
    validClass: 'has-success'
});
```

You can add multiple classes too, although not sure why this would be necessary:

```
$('#contact').validate({
    errorClass: 'error has-error',
    validClass: 'valid has-success'
});
```

See documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

---

> *"it's validating only first field. If I field [sic] your name field and
>   I keep email address blank then also it's submiting form"*

Because you don't have a rule on the second field that would "require" it to be filled out.  You'll need to add the `required` attribute to this field too.

Also, on your first field, `required=""` is not the commonly accepted syntax.

This format is best, IMO:  `required="required"`

Comment: thanks buddy.. one more question is i want to do ajax request on success of form validation... how to recognize that form is validate without error (all fields are fine)?

Comment: @404NotFound, you would put Ajax inside the `submitHandler` callback function.  See the docs.